# Can Salary Sacrifice be used to buy, not lease, a car in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, car

I'm interested in buying an electric car and I'm aware that salary sacrifice can be used to lease one with tax benefits.  I don't like leasing cars as I like to keep them for a long time.  I can't find out if this is possible (assuming my employer is willing to do the necessary paperwork).

I've tried searching here but I can't find a specific question on the subject.

General search is overwhelmed with companies offering leasing solutions, even with specific searches including the words "buy" and "purchase".

The government website doesn't seem to rule it out but doesn't specifically state it's allowed either.

My question in summary: If my employer is happy to do so, is it possible to use salary sacrifice in the UK to purchase, rather than lease, an electric car with the same low BiK tax rate as leasing one?

Comment: I had the impression that you just (can) buy the car at a depreciated value after the 3 year lease period. Did you check the standard leasing schemes for what happens?

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica yes, this is definitely what happens with bikes (I administer the Cycle to Work scheme for my company). It has to be structured as a lease because you need to pay for it over N months (usually 12 for bikes), but you have the option to own it at the end with a lump sum payment.